# Get the total listening time from the CLI with banshee

Tags: command-line, scripts, banshee

Is there a way I can get total listening time from command line? I want to write a script to keep track of how much time I spend listening to music on a daily basis.

Comment: What I ended up writing: https://github.com/deadghost/banshee-listening-time. It's not super pretty but it works. It's inspired by how John Carmack listens to music whenever he's productive and checks how much music he listened to at the end of the day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, using the following command:

```
pgrep banshee
```

you can check if Banshee is running.

If yes, you can use:

```
banshee --query-current-state
```

command in your bash script to get the current Banshee state (if it's playing or not).

Here is some *rudimentary* bash code from which you can start and improve your script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

seconds=0

while : ; do
    if ( pgrep banshee > /dev/null ); then
        if [ "$(banshee --query-current-state | cut -d' ' -f2)" = "playing" ]; then
            (( seconds++ ))
            echo "Total listening time: $seconds seconds"
        fi
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: fantastic addition on "How to". +1 from me.

Comment: I ended up keeping track of time using unix time since `sleep 1` is 1 second plus the time it takes to execute the body of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some *(not console, but with GUI)* time-tracking apps:

#### GTimer:

- Package: gtimer
- Section: universe/utils
- Description:

  > ```
  > GTK-based X11 task timer
  > ```
  >
  > A graphical program that tracks how your time is spent.  Maintains a simple list of tasks, each of which can belong to a project, and allows you
  >   to track time in each.  Multiple clocks can run simultaneously, annotations can be added to a day's time, and reports can be generated in either
  >   HTML or text.  If GTimer detects that you're idle, you are given the option of subtracting off the time you spent idle when you return.
  >
  > Compared to other time tracking applications, GTimer is graphical without depending on a desktop environment and aims for simplicity rather than
  >   attempting to be a full-fledged project tracking and billing application.
- Snapshot:

  [image: snap_gtimer]
- [Homepage](http://www.k5n.us/gtimer.php)
- Installation:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gtimer
  ```

---

#### GTimeLog:

- Package: `gtimelog`
- Section: `universe/admin`
- Description:

  > ```
  > A Gtk+ time tracking application
  > ```
  >
  > Time Tracker (a.k.a. gtimelog) provides a time tracking application to allow the user to track what they work on during the day and how long they spend doing it.
- Snapshot:

  [image: shap1]
- [Homepage](http://mg.pov.lt/gtimelog/)
- Installation:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gtimelog
  ```

---

#### Time Tracker:

- Package: hamster-applet
- Section: universe/gnome
- Description:

  > ```
  > Time tracking applet for GNOME
  > ```
  >
  > Project Hamster helps you to keep track of how much time you spend on various activities during the day.  Whenever you move from one task to
  >   another, you change your current activity in the GNOME applet.
  >
  > It can present graphical statistics of how long you have spent on each task, and may be useful for project management or keeping employee
  >   timesheets.
- Snapshot:

  [image: snap2]
- [Homepage](http://live.gnome.org/ProjectHamster)
- Installation:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install hamster-applet
  ```

  To install AppIndicator for the same:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install hamster-indicator
  ```